# ASP.NET OnClient Click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I have the following button:

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnRequestLeave" runat="server" Text="Request Leave" OnClientClick="return validation();" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="BtnAdd_Click" Width="111px" />
```

how can I check the return value of the `validation();` which is javascript client side validation and if, it is valid call the `OnClick` method ONCE and disable the button similar to the following:

```
this.disabled = true; this.value = 'Submitting...';
```

to disable users from double clicking and thus the `OnClick` method not to be called more than once

EDIT: would something like this work:

```
OnClientClick="if(validation()){this.disabled = true; this.value = 'Submitting...';}else{return validation()};" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="BtnAdd_Click" Width="111px" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your definition to pass button into the function:

```
OnClientClick="return validation(this);"
```

and inside of validation function do something like this

```
function validation(btn){
   if ( /* your condition to pass validation */ ) {
       btn.disabled = true;
       btn.value = 'Submitting...';
       return true  
   } else {
       return false
   }
}
```

If validation passes - you modify button appearance and return true - making postback and server-side `OnClick` possible.
If validation fails you return false canceling postback and server-side click.